# C# Unauthorized Access Exception

Tags: c#

I'm getting an Unauthorized Access Exception when I'm trying to open the file

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        short numberOfLines = Int16.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        webBrowser = new WebBrowser[numberOfLines];
        if (!Directory.Exists(logPath))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(logPath);
        }
        for (short i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++)
        {
            System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(logPath);
            runBrowserThread(i);
        }
    }
```

it says, the access to the path was denied. Where may be the issue?

Comment: hm, to me it sounds like you are unauthorized to access the file.

Comment: StreamWriter takes a file path not a directory path. It isn't documented in StreamWriter, but [many of the File apis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9skfh7s(v=vs.110).aspx) throw UnauthorizedAccessException when you try to open a directory as a file.

Comment: Does `logPath` contain the path of a directory (`Directory.Exists(logPath)`, `Directory.CreateDirectory(logPath)`) or to a file (`new StreamWriter(logPath)`)? It cannot possibly be both at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code is attempting to write to a directory as if it was a file.

When attempting to create files with a file path that references a directory, you'll be presented with an `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

```
if (!Directory.Exists(logPath))
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(logPath);
}
for (short i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++)
{
    System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(logPath);
    runBrowserThread(i);
}
```

The `logPath` variable references the path of a directory, not a file. 
To create a file, you could do something like this...

```
string logPath = @"c:\Logs";
string logFile = Path.Combine(logPath, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("HH-mm-ss") + ".log");

// Directory.CreateDirectory(logPath);

using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(logFile))
{
    writer.WriteLine("testing random log");
}

// Process.Start(logFile);
```

Comment: Had to have more coffie today -_-

Comment: The exception thrown is misleading, I've been caught out by it pretty bad too :)